# How to get coordinates of click on rawImage in Unity using Hololens?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, hololens, mrtk

So right now I have a this hierarchy:
**Cube** → **Canvas** → **RawImage**

And I want to get the coordinates of my click on the rawimage, but I dont know where to start right now.

1. In the HoloToolkit is an GazeManager, where the raycast is performed and there is the property HitPosition. So by using *GazeManager.Instance.HitPosition* I should get the click position in world. But how do I get from this to the coordinates on the Canvas?
2. I can trigger *OnInputClicked(InputClickedEventData eventData)* if I use *IInputClickHandler*. But from the eventData I wont get Information about the click.
3. I found [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/892333/find-xy-cordinates-of-click-on-uiimage-new-gui-sys.html) but cant transfer it into my needs. Because his eventData has more options.
4. I guess there wont be a difference to get the click from the rawimage, or the canvas or the cube, because they have all the same size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe what you need is to change your approach, I can see some solutions for this.

1. Change your `Canvas` from `Overlay` to `World Space` and `Raycast` the click to get a normal position, not `Canvas` position.
2. If you have `Canvas` in `Overlay`, I think that `Input.mousePosition` is directly proportional to `RectTransform.position`, so there is your position.

For both, you can use [IPointerClickHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler.OnPointerClick.html) to detect the click on any UI element.

Comment: My `canvas` is already on worldspace. Ok, I tried OnPointerClick and getting the position via this:

`public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)`  
`{`

`Vector3 hitPosition = transform.InverseTransformPoint(GazeManager.Instance.HitPosition);`
`Vector2 clickedPos = new Vector2(hitPosition.x, hitPosition.y);`
`Client.SetClick((int)Math.Ceiling(clickedPos.x), (int)Math.Ceiling(clickedPos.y));`
`}`

To get the right coordinates I need the local one, right? So I'm using InverseTransformPoint();

Comment: I have another problem. Maybe u know how to fix this. I still have this hierarchy: `Cube → Canvas → RawImage`. My canvas accepts raycast, its has `Graphic Raycaster` and the RawImage accepts raycast too. So the problem is when Im running it on the hololens the cursor appear not alligned to the cube, its like 1cm above. Like if there is a invisible wall in front of the cube. If I deactivate `Graphic Raycaste` on the canvas, my cursor works fine but I cant trigger my `OnInputClicked-Event`.

Comment: The first comment I can't comment because I don't know the GazeManager return values, but for the second one you can change the approach and use a normal Collider for the area where you want to get events, and a normal Raycast launch will 100% get the event.

Comment: I deactivated all the raycast-stuff on cube, canvas and rawimage. Then I added a box collider to the rawimage, set it up the width and height (same resolution like my image/video) and it worked fine.

Comment: The next issue I had was that the coordinates where not right -> So I looked up my pivot/zero point -> pivot was in the centre -> set it to left top corner for my needs and multiplied the y-coordinates with negative one, so I had a inverted coordinate system